# Trouble adding printviewdialog to windows form

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a Windows Form Application and im having trouble adding a printviewdialog to the form itself. Code below pop-ups the printviewdialog before displaying the form.

Code:

```
//Variables
PrintPreviewDialog printViewDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   initComponents();
}

public void initComponents()
{
   printViewDialog.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 400);
   printViewDialog.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
   printViewDialog.ShowDialog();
   this.Controls.Add(printViewDialog);
}
```

Getting an error at: "this.Controls.Add(printViewDialog);"

Error: "Cant add element of highest niveau to another element."

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
printViewDialog.TopLevel = false;
```

before you add it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used PrintPreviewControl to solve my problem, thanks anyways guys!

Dragged PrintPreviewControl into my form, and used the code below for some of my settings:

```
//Get responsive width and height.
System.Drawing.Rectangle workingRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
int height = workingRectangle.Height;
int width = workingRectangle.Width / 100 * 75;

//Settings printPreviewControl
printPreviewControl1.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);
printPreviewControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```